# Change home_url in searchform.php to go to HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: php, https

Everything in my site goes to `HTTPS` except for one searchbox that insists on using `http` which gives my site an insecure alert in Chrome. Im using WP 4.9.6 with the Spacious Theme. The search box uses `searchform.php` and appears to request `home_url` from there. Both my WordPress URL and my Site URL both contain `https://sitename.com`.

Here is the content of the `searchform.php` file:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="search-form searchform clearfix" method="get">
<div class="search-wrap">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'spacious' ); ?>" class="s field" name="s">
    <button class="search-icon" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

I have tried to replace `home_url` with the actual URL including HTTPS, which fixes the page insecure alert, but removes the search box -- so that doesn't seem to work. I reached out to the ThemeGrill folks and they recommended running a plugin to force every `http` entry to `https` but that also did not work.

I hope one of ya'll can point me in the right direction. Im running this locally on a Cent box.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: `home_url` should be returning https URLs if your sites HTTPS is setup correctly, but since it doesn't, something somewhere has not been changed or set correctly. Are you sure you fully migrated from http to https? That everything in the DB was changed? That your sites URL in options has https not http? That the `wp-config.php` constants are all set?

Comment: Check also the `.htaccess` in your root of the install; maybe this file have rules for this mistake. The code of the `searchform.php` is not the point for this wrong protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the tips yall. Im going to try to grep the entire directory for any http entries and see if something got skipped. Definitely have them correct in options and I used a plugin called WordPress HTTPS to apply HTTPS as well as a plugin to replaced any http with https. I'll update this shortly.

Comment: Still not having any luck with this. I've ran `grep -rnw . -e "http://sitename.com" and could not find any listings. I went through `.htaccess` as well and tried to put a redirect in there for the page with the issues, but it's still giving me an issue. Any other ideas?